# Error initializing non-const type in constructor initializer?

Tags: c++

The error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}’
```

the code:

```
class MyClass {
private:
  // why does this need to be a const reference?
  std::istream &fin;
};


MyClass::MyClass(std::string &filename,const char quote, const char sep)
  : fin(std::ifstream(filename)), owns_stream(true), sep(sep), quote(quote)
{
}
```

This works if I make the private fin member const. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're initialising a reference from a temporary. Only `const` references can do that … though it actually *doesn't* "work", because you have a dangling reference. This particular usage of reference-binding *will not extend the temporary's life*.

> `[C++14: 12.2/5]:` *[..]* The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.
> - *[..]*

The conventional way to do this is to accept a stream into the constructor in the first place:

```
MyClass(std::istream& strm, const char quote, const char sep)
  : fin(strm), owns_stream(true), sep(sep), quote(quote)
{}
```

Then:

```
std::ifstream ifs("/tmp/something");
MyClass obj(ifs);
```

This is far more flexible for your users.

Otherwise, if you wish to mandate the use of `std::ifstream` specifically, just store an actual `std::ifstream` and drop the entire temporary/reference business:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass(const std::string& filename)
      : fin(filename)
   {}

private:
  std::ifstream fin;
};
```

Comment: ok, makes sense.  I have another constructor that takes a stream, I mostly wanted the second constructor for convenience in the case that the user really didn't want to manage the lifetime of the stream itself.

Comment: Sorry, thought I had marked as answer already.  The only way I can think of to reasonably do this is to use an istream pointer internally and allocate it on the heap if they pass in a filename or take the address if they pass in the stream (and do/don't delete based upon whether I have ownership or not).  Is there another approach I'm missing?

Comment: @Fred: That's probably what I'd do (if I decided it were _really_ worth the trouble).